# Crypto Module not Found for pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, modulenotfounderror

I want to turn my Python script into a single executable with all the dependencies in place. For this purpose I am using `pyinstaller`. I have installed it globally on my machine and set up a virtualenv for my project. While the virtualenv is active I am executing the following command:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --paths /path/to/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages script.py
```

This creates an executable but when I try to run it it gives me:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto.Util.Padding'
```

In the warning file it gives me the following line:

```
missing module named 'Crypto.Util.Padding' - imported by sp_api.base.helpers (top-level)
```

And during executable generation the output includes:

```
6427 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-Crypto.py' from '/home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib/hooks/stdhooks'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto.Math'
```

When executing the command

```
pyinstaller --onefile myscript.py
```

under windows, it works perfectly fine even without specifying the venv path. When performing the same step in linux, the executable fails with the first non-standard import (flask in this case).

Comment: You may need to add those imports to the `.spec` file.

Comment: @BoarGules What do you mean with "those"? I tried adding `--hidden-import Crypto.Util.Padding` but that did not change anything

Answer (score 1):

After also adding the path for `lib64` from the corresponding venv the `Crypto` library is found.

```
pyinstaller --onefile --paths /path/to/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages \
   --paths /path/to/venv/lib64/python3.9/site-packagesscript.py
```